# Change Parent style while Child is renderd

Tags: css, typescript, react-typescript

Hello im trying to Change the style from .content while `<Spin className="spin">` is renderd.

Typescript:

```
public render() {
        return (
            this.state.isLoading ? (<Spin className="spin" />) : (
                <div>
                    <FormStructure {...this.state.system} />
                </div>
            ));
    }
```

CSS:

```
.content-inner {
    display: block;
    align-items: initial;
    justify-content: initial;
}

.spin > content-inner {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to change the style of `content-inner` only if the child `ant-spin` exists? Short answer: You cannot.

Long answer is that the styles for the DOM are applied in order, so by the time the browser reaches the child div, the browser cannot apply any style to the parent div, anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Add an event to child component, which will notify parent about loading state.

Parent Component:

```
<div className={classnames(style.contentInner, this.state.isLoading && style.contentInnerLoading)}>
  <Loader
    onChangeLoadingState={(isLoading: boolean) => {
      this.setState({ isLoading })
    }}
  />
</div>
```